# checking the value of Nth column of all txt files recursively

Tags: python

I have directory tree like this:

```
- /home/python
    - file1.sh
    - file2.py
    - dirA
        - file1.txt
        - file2.txt
    - dirB
        - file3.txt
        - file5.txt
    - another
        - file6.txt
        - file10.txt
    - file11
```

This is a sample of one file (all files have the following sample and line counts are exactly the same, all files have two parts and are separated by two `>` signs):

```
> this is first output and some another contents
these are
some test lines
to fill the file
Testing download speed
Download: 0.00 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed
Upload: 0.00 Mbit/s
> this is second output but other texts go here too
these are
some test lines
to fill the file
Testing download speed
Download: 1200.58 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed
Upload: 857.25 Kbit/s
```

I'm going to perform this (all `.txt` files have two parts: `> this is first output` and `> this is second output` and these are the same in all files at the beginning of the lines):

```
first, find line containing `this is first output`, then find `Download` string, then
if third column is Mbit:
    if second column is zero:
        print(f'Download1 speed of {filename} is zero.')
    elif second column is less than 600:
        print(f'Download1 speed of {filename} less than 600 Mbits.')
elif third column is Kbit:
    print(f'Download1 speed of {filename} is {value} Kbit/s.')
then, find line containing `this is first output`, then find `Upload` string, then
if third column is Mbit:
    if second column is zero:
        print(f'Upload1 speed of {filename} is zero.')
    elif second column is less than 600:
        print(f'Upload1 speed of {filename} less than 600 Mbits.')
elif third column is Kbit:
    print(f'Upload1 speed of {filename} is {value} Kbit/s.')
```

And the above condition goes true for the `Upload` too.

This is my attempt so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from pathlib import Path
result = list(Path(".").rglob("*.txt"))

for filename in result:
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            with open('log.txt', 'a') as log:
                if 'Download:' in line:
                    if line.split()[2] == 'Mbit/s':
                        # if float(line.split()[1]) == 0.00:
                        #     log.write(f'Download Speed of {filename} is Zero Mbit/s.\n')
                        if float(line.split()[1]) < 20.00 and float(line.split()[1]) != 0.00:
                            log.write(f'Download Speed of {filename} is {line.split()[1]} Mbit/s.\n')
                    if line.split()[2] == 'Kbit/s':
                        log.write(f'Download Speed of {filename} is {line.split()[1]} Kbit/s.\n')
                if 'Upload:' in line:
                    if line.split()[2] == 'Mbit/s':
                        # if float(line.split()[1]) == 0.00:
                        #     log.write(f'Upload Speed of {filename} is Zero Mbit/s.\n')
                        if float(line.split()[1]) < 20.00 and float(line.split()[1]) != 0.00:
                            log.write(f'Upload Speed of {filename} is {line.split()[1]} Mbit/s.\n')
                    if line.split()[2] == 'Kbit/s':
                        log.write(f'Upload Speed of {filename} is {line.split()[1]} Kbit/s.\n')
```

Expected output:

```
Download1 speed of dirA/file1.txt is zero.
Upload1 speed of dirA/file1.txt zero.
Download2 speed of dirA/file1.txt is 1200.58 Mbit/s.
Upload2 speed of dirA/file1.txt is 857.25 Kbit/s.
```

Comment: I can merely do in `Tkinter` without using `if/else` block.

Answer (score 1):

for extracting lines with download/upload data use python3 [regular expressions](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/regex-cheatsheet/). These are useful since they don't totally rely on a specific file format/structure for your `.txt` files.

suppose this is `./ex1.txt`

```
> this is first output and some another contents
these are
some test lines
to fill the file
Testing download speed
Download: 0.00 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed
Upload: 0.00 Mbit/s
> this is second output but other texts go here too
these are
some test lines
to fill the file
Testing download speed
Download: 1200.58 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed
Upload: 857.25 Kbit/s
```

```py
import re
from glob import glob

for pathh in glob("**/*.txt", recursive=True):
    with open(pathh, 'r') as fh:
        text = fh.read()

    download_pattern = r'(?:^download: )(.*$)'
    upload_pattern = r'(?:^upload: )(.*$)'

    downloads = re.findall(download_pattern, text, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
    uploads = re.findall(upload_pattern, text, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)

    if len(downloads) != 2 or len(uploads) != 2:
        print(f'skipping {pathh}: is ill formatted')
        continue
    # assuming we found 4 matches / file is well formatted
    for i, (d, u) in enumerate(zip(downloads, uploads)):
        print(f'{pathh}: download_{i+1}_speed: {d}\n{pathh}: upload_{i+1}_speed: {u}')
```

the code outputs this *and it does work for nested directories with *.txt files.

```
ex1.txt: download_1_speed: 0.00 Mbit/s
ex1.txt: upload_1_speed: 0.00 Mbit/s
ex1.txt: download_2_speed: 1200.58 Mbit/s
ex1.txt: upload_2_speed: 857.25 Kbit/s
```

note that this isn't a good format to log to, it would be much better to parse the strings in the  download and upload lists into a csv or dataframe for better logs but yea. as for how it works, you loop over all *.txt files and match any lines that start with `download:`  or `upload:`  and print the logs to the console.

## regex pattern breakdown

`(?:^download: )(.*$)`

1. `(?:^download: )` this means find lines which start with the string `download:` . the `?:` at the start is to avoid capturing the group since we only care about the speed and units *if we don't include the `?:` you would get 2 groups `download:`  and `0.00 kbs`
2. `(.*$)` this means match everything uptill the end of the line i.e till \n and capture the group -> this ends up being the speeds and the units like `1200.58 Mbit/s`

love sleepy.

Answer (score 1):

If the files are all consistent in line numbers, then chunking each parts in the file would be easy. You may also extract information other than speed for each part.

Defining constants:

```
LINES_PER_PART = 8
PARTS_PER_FILE = 2
```

Starting from your own code:

```
result = list(Path(".").rglob("*.txt"))

for filename in result:
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
```

Next step is to get each parts from file

```
# In main() function
lines = file.readlines()
parts = chunks(lines, LINES_PER_PART)

# ...

def chunks(arr, chunk_size):
    result = []
    for i in range(0, len(arr), chunk_size):
        result.append(arr[i:i+chunk_size])

    return result
```

Now we just process each part:

```
for i, part in enumerate(parts, 1):
    # Download speed is on the 3rd line from the bottom
    download_info = parse_speed_info(part[-3])
    # Upload speed is the last line
    upload_info = parse_speed_info(part[-1])

    print(f"Download{i} speed of {filename} is {stringify_speed_info(*download_info)}.")
    print(f"Upload{i} speed of {filename} is {stringify_speed_info(*upload_info)}.")
    print()
```

And here's the needed functions:

```
def parse_speed_info(string):
    # Ignore the 'Download:'/'Upload:' part
    speed_info_list = string.split()[1::]

    return (
        float(speed_info_list[0]),
        speed_info_list[1]
    )


def stringify_speed_info(speed, unit):
    if speed == 0:
        return "zero"
    elif speed < 600.0:
        return f"less than 600 {unit}"

    return f"{speed} {unit}"
```

Here's the full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from pathlib import Path

LINES_PER_PART = 8
PARTS_PER_FILE = 2


def main():
    result = list(Path(".").rglob("*.txt"))

    for filename in result:
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
            parts = chunks(lines, LINES_PER_PART)

            for i, part in enumerate(parts, 1):
                download_info = parse_speed_info(part[-3])
                upload_info = parse_speed_info(part[-1])

                print(f"Download{i} speed of {filename} is {stringify_speed_info(*download_info)}.")
                print(f"Upload{i} speed of {filename} is {stringify_speed_info(*upload_info)}.")
                print()


def chunks(arr, chunk_size):
    result = []
    for i in range(0, len(arr), chunk_size):
        result.append(arr[i:i+chunk_size])

    return result


def parse_speed_info(string):
    speed_info_list = string.split()[1::]

    return (
        float(speed_info_list[0]),
        speed_info_list[1]
    )


def stringify_speed_info(speed, unit):
    if speed == 0:
        return "zero"
    elif speed < 600.0:
        return f"less than 600 {unit}"

    return f"{speed} {unit}"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Let me know if you need anything!